# Is it possible to set blanket resource limit for ALL containers started by docker?

Tags: docker, limit

I run docker as part of a larger system and some services are ran on bare metal while other are in docker containers. Docker services are created by users at run time and quite often they consume all system resources causing OOM killer start shooting at random. What I ideally want to achieve is to limit ALL processes started by docker to 90% of CPU and 50% or RAM. There is no shortage of information on how to limit those resources on per container basis but I rather want to set them on "per docker service" basis and let containers run loose. Is it possible? Does anyone found a solution?

Comment: if you run `docker info` it will display the "Total Memory" for the docker process. Maybe if you lower that docker will not spin up more containers after it has used all of its memory.

Comment: @quasar `docker info` shows the total memory of the host and this is exactly what I want to limit - to set it to 50% of total memory. I'm exploring cgroups but not sure yet if it is the right direction.